# Retrieve all the values that are in the the row with the max value

Tags: mysql, group-by, max

I have a table that looks like this:

[image]

For each COMPANY there are multiple NATURAL_PERSON_ID, every NATURAL_PERSON have a date in which an audit was performed FECHA_DE_REPORTE and as a company there is a date in which the first loan was give to that company.

What I want is to select for each NATURAL_PERSON all the FOLIO_CONSULTA whose FECHA_DE_REPORTE is less or equal to FIRST_LOAN (the date in which the first loan was given for that company) Then I need to find the MAX date among each group and keep al the information (the whole row) for the value that fulfills all these conditions, and all this for each NATURAL_PERSON

So for this example the result I expected is all the information of the second row since this is the MAX() of FECHA_DE_REPORTE by COMPANY AND NATURAL_PERSON.

I have tried:

```
SELECT NPC.COMPANY_ID
      ,NPC.NATURAL_PERSON_ID
      ,NPS.DIGITAL_SIGNATURE_ID
      ,CDC.FOLIO_CONSULTA
      ,CDC.FECHA_DE_REPORTE
      ,FIRST_LOAN.FIRST_LOAN
      ,MAX(CDC.FECHA_DE_REPORTE)  MAX_FOLIO_CONSUTA
    FROM KONFIO.NATURAL_PERSON_COMPANY NPC
    LEFT JOIN KONFIO.NATURAL_PERSON_SIGNATURE NPS ON NPS.NATURAL_PERSON_ID = NPC.NATURAL_PERSON_ID
    JOIN KONFIO.CDC_RESPONSE CDC ON CDC.DIGITAL_SIGNATURE_ID= NPS.DIGITAL_SIGNATURE_ID
    JOIN
    (
    SELECT CAPP.COMPANY_ID
      ,MIN(LOAN.DOCUMENTATION_DATE) FIRST_LOAN
    FROM KONFIO.COMPANY_APPLICATION CAPP
    JOIN KONFIO.LOAN ON LOAN.APPLICATION_ID = CAPP.APPLICATION_ID
    GROUP BY CAPP.COMPANY_ID) FIRST_LOAN ON FIRST_LOAN.COMPANY_ID = NPC.COMPANY_ID
    WHERE CDC.FECHA_DE_REPORTE <= FIRST_LOAN.FIRST_LOAN
    AND NPC.COMPANY_ID IN (1033) 
    GROUP BY NPC.COMPANY_ID, NPC.NATURAL_PERSON_ID
```

but it retrieves the first value that finds so the FOLIO_CONSULTA does not correspond to the FOLIO_CONSULTA of the MAX() FECHA_DE_REPORTE

[image]

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should join the subquery for MAX(FECHA_DE_REPORTE)  on  table CDC_RESPONSE

```
    SELECT NPC.COMPANY_ID
      ,NPC.NATURAL_PERSON_ID
      ,NPS.DIGITAL_SIGNATURE_ID
      ,CDC.FOLIO_CONSULTA
      ,CDC.FECHA_DE_REPORTE
      ,FIRST_LOAN.FIRST_LOAN
      ,T.MAX_FOLIO_CONSUTA
    FROM KONFIO.NATURAL_PERSON_COMPANY NPC
    INNER JOIN  (
        SELECT DIGITAL_SIGNATURE_ID
             , MAX(FECHA_DE_REPORTE)  MAX_FOLIO_CONSUTA
        FROM KONFIO.CDC_RESPONSE
        GROUP BY DIGITAL_SIGNATURE_ID
    ) T ON T.DIGITAL_SIGNATURE_ID = NPS.DIGITAL_SIGNATURE_ID 
        AND T.MAX_FOLIO_CONSUTA = CDC.FECHA_DE_REPORTE
    LEFT JOIN KONFIO.NATURAL_PERSON_SIGNATURE NPS ON NPS.NATURAL_PERSON_ID = NPC.NATURAL_PERSON_ID
    JOIN KONFIO.CDC_RESPONSE CDC ON CDC.DIGITAL_SIGNATURE_ID= NPS.DIGITAL_SIGNATURE_ID
    JOIN
    (
    SELECT CAPP.COMPANY_ID
      ,MIN(LOAN.DOCUMENTATION_DATE) FIRST_LOAN
    FROM KONFIO.COMPANY_APPLICATION CAPP
    JOIN KONFIO.LOAN ON LOAN.APPLICATION_ID = CAPP.APPLICATION_ID
    GROUP BY CAPP.COMPANY_ID) FIRST_LOAN ON FIRST_LOAN.COMPANY_ID = NPC.COMPANY_ID
    WHERE CDC.FECHA_DE_REPORTE <= FIRST_LOAN.FIRST_LOAN
    AND NPC.COMPANY_ID IN (1033) 
    GROUP BY NPC.COMPANY_ID, NPC.NATURAL_PERSON_ID
    ...... missing part
```